# Ruby - Error when trying to install a gem (undefined method 'from')

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mongoid

Help! I'm trying to install the Mongoid gem:

If I run 'gem install mongoid' I get the following:

```
> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
>     undefined method `from' for Gem::Package::TarHeader:Class
```

If I include mongoid in my gemfile like the following, and then run bundle:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
source "http://gems.rubyforge.org"
source "http://gemcutter.org"

gem "mongoid", "~> 2.0"
```

I get...

```
bundle
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Fetching source index for http://gems.rubyforge.org/
Fetching source index for http://gemcutter.org/
/Users/lsayers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:58:in `block in each': undefined method `from' for Gem::Package::TarHeader:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:55:in `loop'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb:35:in `initialize'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb:20:in `new'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb:20:in `open'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package.rb:44:in `open'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/format.rb:62:in `from_io'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/format.rb:46:in `block in from_file_by_path'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/format.rb:45:in `from_file_by_path'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:100:in `spec_from_gem'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/source.rb:77:in `fetch'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:50:in `block in run'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:49:in `run'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/cli.rb:222:in `install'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /Users/lsayers/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

I don't know what's going on??? It looks like an error with the gem, but I'm thinking maybe it's my machine or something else?

Comment: What version of ruby gems are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the question brian, I ran rvm rubygems latest and then rvm gem install mongoid, and it works :) bundle runs fine now :)

Comment: Glad it lead you to your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I ran:

```
rvm rubygems latest
```

and then

```
rvm gem install mongoid
```

and it works :) bundle runs fine now :)